# View Keeps Crashing and returning to previous view

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

I am having some trouble when I run my app on a physical phone. I have two screens where I am showing a list of matches that the user can choose from and if the user clicks on a match, it brings them to a page that displays more details. I accomplish this like this(The list of matches is shown in Available Matches):

```
struct Post: View {
var match: Matches
@EnvironmentObject var user: UserModel
@ObservedObject var model = MatchModel()
@State var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

@State var otherUser: [User] = []

@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        
        
        
        Text("The playing time is " + dateFormatter.string(from: match.time))
        Text("The location is " + match.location)
        
        Text("The players are : ")
        ForEach(otherUser) { user in
            Text(user.name)
        }.padding(5)
        
        Button {
            model.updatePlayers(updateMatch: match, uid: user.fetchUID())
            dismiss()
        } label: {
            Text("Accept Post")
        }
        
    }.onAppear{
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, hh:mm"
        
        for x in 0...match.players.count-1 {
            user.fetchOtherUser(uid: match.players[x]) {
                print("the players are " + match.players[x])
                self.otherUser.append(contentsOf: user.otherUser)
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}
struct AvailableMatches: View {
@State private var isShowing = false

@State private var showingPopover = false
@ObservedObject var matchesListViewModel = MatchListViewModel()
@State var isShowingDetailView = false
@EnvironmentObject var userModel: UserModel
@State var user: User = User(id: "", email: "", profileImageUrl: "", name: "", rating: 0.0)
@State var numberPlayers = 2
@State var selectedDate = Date()
@State var name = ""
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        ZStack {
            if isShowing {
                SideMenuView(isShowing: $isShowing, user: user)
            }
            VStack {
                List(matchesListViewModel.MatchViewModels) { matc in
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: Post(match: matc.match), label: {
                        MatchView(viewModel: matc)
                    })
                }
                
                Spacer()
                Button("New Post") {
                    showingPopover = true
                }.popover(isPresented: $showingPopover) {
                    newPost()//.font(.headline).padding()
                }
                
            }.listStyle(InsetListStyle())
                .navigationTitle("Availbile Matches")
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                    withAnimation(.spring()){
                        isShowing.toggle()
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }))
                .cornerRadius(isShowing ? 20 : 10)
                .offset(x: isShowing ? 300 : 0, y: 0)
                .scaleEffect(isShowing ? 0.8 : 1)
                .onAppear {
                    isShowing = false
                    userModel.fetchUser {
                        
                        print(userModel.user.count)
                        for i in userModel.user {
                            
                            if i.uid == userModel.fetchUID() {
                                user = i
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
        }
    }
    
  }

}
```

This works perfectly fine on this page. I also do something very similar in the Account View but when I click on a post to call the Post Struct, the view opens up for a second(with the correct information) but immediately closes. The structs are nearly identical.

```
struct Account: View {
@EnvironmentObject var userModel: UserModel
@ObservedObject var model = MatchModel()

@ObservedObject var matchesListViewModel = MatchListViewModelUser()

lazy var userMatches: [Matches] = []
@State var email = "No user foundx"
@State var uid = "No user foundx"

@State var user: User = User(id: "", email: "", profileImageUrl: "", name: "", rating: 0.0)
@State var otherUser: [User] = []
@State var finalUser: User = User(id: "", email: "", profileImageUrl: "", name: "", rating: 0.0)


@State var m: String = ""
var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        Text("Hi " + user.name)
        Text("hey " + uid)
        Text("Whats good" + m)
        List(matchesListViewModel.MatchViewModels) { matc in
            
            NavigationLink(destination: Post(match: matc.match), label: {
                MatchViewUser(viewModel: matc)
            })
        }
       
    } .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
        .navigationBarTitle("My Matches", displayMode: .inline)
         
    .onAppear(perform: {
        email = userModel.fetchEmail()
        uid = userModel.fetchUID()
        
        m = userModel.googleFetchStuff()
        userModel.fetchUser {
            
            for i in userModel.user {
                if i.uid == userModel.fetchUID() {
                    user = i
                }
            }
        }
    })
    
  }
}
```

The odd part is that everything works correctly when I run it on the simulator. It's very strange and I don't know why it is happening. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What does this `dismiss()` do?

Comment: Dismiss is a way I close the post once a match has been accepted. Once the "Accept Post" Button has been clicked, it closes the post view and returns to the previous view of matches

Comment: Ah, I see. I am trying to find the tie-in to Firebase since the question is tagged that way. This seems like just a coding error in SwiftUI - where is the Firebase code that's causing issues?

Comment: Apologies, I don't fully know whether it is a swiftui problem or a firebase problem as the list is generated from Firebase, the matchesListViewModel is a repository connected to my firestore which contains all the matches.

Comment: Does `matchesListViewModel` contain the data you expect? The var names you're using is a bit odd `matchesListViewModel.MatchViewModels` makes it look like `MatchViewModels` is a *Class* or *Structure* model definition. In coding, Class. Structure and Enums start with Capital letters and instances of those or properties ("vars" or "variables") start with lowerCase

Comment: You are correct, the naming scheme is a bit off but the matchesListViewModel does contain the data I expect, it has all the correct matches but the view crashes immediately when displaying the data.

Comment: The verbiage in the question is little confusing - using the words 'screens', 'pages' and 'views'. Are those all referring to the same thing? Is this a Master->Detail setup? Assuming the Account view is the master - it opens a Post view. But then where does the AvailableMatches view come into play? Reducing the code in the question would be helpful - take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)